# Table, insert x cells inside with javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, dom, clone

### GOAL:

#### Create a board with user number grid. CSS, HTML works when tested.

1. Reproduce `(x)` with the length (and width for that matter) of the table.
2. Create `(x)` rows and `(x)` columns in the table with this var `x`.

I know javascript inside and out... as far as math. Just point me in the right direction to create 3 `TR`s and 3 `TD`s inside of each `TR` at the same time in the DOM.

I've tried `.clone`, but I have been failing... any help is appreciated!

ORIGINAL JS:

```
function create(x){
    var board = [];
    for(var i=0;i<x;i++){
        var tempArr = [];
        for(var j=0;j<x;j++){ tempArr[j] = ""; }
        board.push(tempArr);
    }
    return board;
}
create(3);
```

**FULL HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tic Tac Toe! (and more...)</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Tic Tac Toe">
  <meta name="author" content="SinSysOnline">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  body{
    font-family:"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
  }
  td{
    border-right:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:72px;
  }
  td:last-child{
    border-right:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
  }
  tr:last-child td{
    border-bottom:none;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="dashboard">
    <input type="text" value="How large is your grid? (default 3)" size="35" />
</div>

<table id="board">
    <tr></tr>
</table>

<script>
(function($) {
    var $board = $('#board');
    var td = "<td></td>", $tr = $("<tr></tr>");
    function create(x) {
        $board.empty();
        var arr = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            arr.push(td);
        }
        var $trCloned = $tr.clone().append(arr.join(''));
        for(var j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            $board.append($trCloned);
        }
    }

    function compChoice(x){
        var a = Math.floor(Math.random(10)*x),
            b = Math.floor(Math.random(10)*x);
        while(board[a][b]!==""){
            a = Math.floor(Math.random(10)*x);
            b = Math.floor(Math.random(10)*x);
        }
        board[a][b]="X";
    }   

    function userChoice(a,b){
        var select = [a,b];
        if(board[a][b]!==""){
            alert("That's not a valid move... try again");
        } else { 
            board[a][b]="O"; 
        }
    }

    var x = prompt("How large would you like your grid? (3-10)");
    var board = create(x);
})(jQuery);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**FULL JS:**

```
(function($) {
var $board = $('#board');
var td = "<td></td>", $tr = $("<tr></tr>");
    function create(x) {
        $board.empty();
        var arr = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            arr.push(td);
        }
        var $trCloned = $tr.clone().append(arr.join(''));
        for(var j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            $board.append($trCloned);
        }
    }

    function compChoice(x){
        var a = Math.floor(Math.random(10)*x),
            b = Math.floor(Math.random(10)*x);
        while(board[a][b]!==""){
            a = Math.floor(Math.random(10)*x);
            b = Math.floor(Math.random(10)*x);
        }
        board[a][b]="X";
    }   

    function userChoice(a,b){
        var select = [a,b];
        if(board[a][b]!==""){
            alert("That's not a valid move... try again");
        } else { 
            board[a][b]="O"; 
        }
    }

    var x = prompt("How large would you like your grid? (3-10)");
    var board = create(x);
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a nested loop would be much easier.
Exmaple: http://jsfiddle.net/7qmdY/

```
$("#go").click(function(){
    var size = $("#size").attr("value");//get size value;
    for(var i=0;i < size;i++){// first loop to create row
        $("#board").append("<tr>");
        for(var j=0;j < size;j++){// nested loop to create column in all rows
            $("#board").append("<td>1</td>");
        }
        $("#board").append("</tr>");
    }
});
```

Comment: You, my friend, are the MAN! (or woman, considering the word Crystal in your name)

Comment: I love solutions that don't do what I'm intending, so I can expand and learn accordingly :-) Thank you again!

Comment: Decided to just use some dynamically created IDs to solve the problem. View here: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HNjMR/)